# Why does this method of convergence fail? $\sum^\infty_{n=3}\frac{1}{n\ln n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

**Question** Does $\sum^\infty_{n=3}\frac{1}{n\ln n}$ converge or diverge?

**Attempt**. I went with the fact that $\ln n<\sqrt n$ for all $n\geq0$. And proceeded to attempt the direct comparison test: $$\sum^\infty_{n=3}\frac{1}{n\ln n}\leq \sum^\infty_{n=3}\frac{1}{n\sqrt n}=\sum^\infty_{n=3}\frac{1}{n^{\frac32}}$$ which by the p-series, $\frac32\geq 1$ hence the right part converges, so the $\sum^\infty_{n=3}\frac{1}{n\ln n}$ should as well, but I've seen this sum to be divergent by the integral method. Where is my mistake?

Comment: If $\ln n<\sqrt n$ then $$
\frac{1}{{\ln n}} > \frac{1}{{\sqrt n }}
$$ is the right implication. You may use the integral test or the Cauchy condensation test to prove the divergence of your original series instead.

Comment: ahhh right, taking the reciprocal on both sides flips the inequality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error lies in assuming that $\ln n<\sqrt n\implies\frac1{n\ln n}<\frac1{n\sqrt n}$. Actually, it's the other way around.

Note the$$\int_3^\infty\frac{\mathrm dx}{x\ln x}=\lim_{M\to\infty}\ln(\ln M))-\ln(\ln(3))=\infty.$$Therefore, your series diverges.